# Android volley does not send POST values after updating android studio

Tags: php, android, android-studio, post, android-volley

I am sending the POST values from my android code using Volley StringRequest...Before Updating my android studio it works perfectly but after updating, I am not getting any POST value from android and I am unable to get where is the problem in my android code or in server side. can anybody tell me hot to solve this problem.

Here is my android code.

```
public class PostRequestTest extends AppCompatActivity {
String URL = "http://.....";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post_request_test);
    SendData();
}

private void SendData()
{
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response)
                {
                    Log.d("Response",response);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(PostRequestTest.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            })
    {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()
        {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("user_name","uname");
            return params;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}}
```

And in PHP I simply print my username but unable to get any value

```
<?php echo $_POST['user_name']; ?>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: you are sending  get request instead of post??

Comment: Please explain again your query as you want to post something but using get method how it could be possible ?

Comment: simply change 
Request.Method.GET => Request.Method.POST

Comment: POST request is also not working. :(

Answer (score 0):

I thinks the Problem is with String Reques. Instead use Json Object Request for Post.

```
JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
obj.put("user_name","user_name");

JsonObjectRequest request=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,your_url,obj,new Response.Listener<String>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response)
                {
                    Log.d("Response",response);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(PostRequestTest.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            })
```